# Additional column that records the row number automatically in a copy activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a Copy Activity in my ADF Pipeline which copies an excel worksheet data to a JSON sink. I am looking for a way to add a custom column that can keep a track of the row number while copying the data. For example,

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 123 |
| DEF | 456 |
| GHI | 789 |

The above should be converted into the below JSON:

```
[{
   "Name": "ABC",
   "Value": "123",
   "Row Number": 1
},
{
   "Name": "DEF",
   "Value": "456",
   "Row Number": 2
},
{
   "Name": "GHI",
   "Value": "789",
   "Row Number": 3
}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Copy activity is not suited for this requirement. You will have to use Mapping data flow in ADF.

Here are the sequence of transformations that are required to achieve your scenario:

1. First Source transformation
2. Derived Column transformation
3. Window Transformation
4. Sink Transformation

This has been answered in Microsoft Q&A forum with step by step implementation using Mapping dataflow : https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/419209/index.html

Answer (score 1):

you probably need to use mapping data flow in ADF, and use the rowNumber() expression to achieve this.